# mocking doesn't give return option

Tags: c#, mocking, nunit, moq

I am doing nunit testing using moq farmework. For some reasons I can't not get Returns option
it should be like below

```
mock.Setup(foo => foo.Execute(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(true)
    .Callback((string s) => calls.Add(s));


but I can only write code like this 
mock.Setup(foo => foo.Execute(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Callback((string s) => calls.Add(s));
```

it wont give me the Returns option. Any suggestions why it is doing this?

Comment: Does your `Execute` function return a bool?

Comment: Can you show us your interface for this mock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method in the interface probably doesn't return `bool`. See the below example:

[image]